# Error deploying CXF web service on JBoss

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf

I created a CXF web service that runs smoothly on tomcat. When I tried to deploy it on JBoss 5.1 I got the following error:

```
10:29:20,476 INFO  [LogNotificationListener] Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@724a2dd4[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
10:29:25,854 ERROR [ProfileDeployAction] Failed to add deployment: [proprietary-jar-1]-1.3.jar
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Unable to find class path entry ClassPathEntryImpl{path=[war-name]/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar} from [proprietary-jar-1]-1.3.jar
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.structure.VFSStructureBuilder.applyContextInfo(VFSStructureBuilder.java:188)
    at org.jboss.deployers.structure.spi.helpers.AbstractStructureBuilder.populateContext(AbstractStructureBuilder.java:82)
```

Both jars are inside the deployed [WAR-FILE]/WEB-INF/lib.

I've read a bunch or articles on class loading isolation levels, cxf and web-service integration on JBOSS (how to turn off web services stack), but nothing seems to solve this..

here goes the war project dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ application ---
[INFO] [war project]:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-2]:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile (version managed from 2.1)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile (version managed from 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.4.0:compile (version managed from 2.0.2)
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile (version managed from 1.2)
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-3]:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-4]:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ([proprietary-jar-5]:1.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.3.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 2.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.3.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 2.1.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.0.7.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.8:compile - version managed from 1.6.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.4; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- struts:struts:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-6]:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile - version managed from 1.8.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 2.1.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile - version managed from 1.8; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 2.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile - version managed from 1.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - version managed from 3.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile - version managed from 1.2.16; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.owasp:csrfguard:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-7]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-8]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ([proprietary-jar-4]:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- ([proprietary-jar-3]:2.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (struts:struts:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- ([proprietary-jar-6]:jar:1.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-2]:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (struts:struts:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-9]:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-10]:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-11]:jar:2.0.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-6]:jar:1.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-12]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- de.vdb:IBANConverter:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-2]:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-16]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.patterntesting:patterntesting-rt:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile - version managed from 1.6.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.patterntesting:patterntesting-check-ct:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.patterntesting:patterntesting-rt:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile - version managed from 1.6.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.patterntesting:patterntesting-check-rt:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.patterntesting:patterntesting-rt:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile - version managed from 1.6.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.patterntesting:patterntesting-concurrent:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.patterntesting:patterntesting-rt:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile - version managed from 1.6.9.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.oval:oval:jar:1.40:compile
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-7]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-14]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-8]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile - version managed from 1.2.16; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (struts:struts:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-4]:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- [proprietary-jar-5]:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8:compile - version managed from 1.6.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile - version managed from 1.8.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - version managed from 2.5; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile - version managed from 1.2.16; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-3]:2.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-11]:jar:2.0.0.23:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 3.0.6.RELEASE; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- [proprietary-jar-1]:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile - version managed from 1.3; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-13]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- ([proprietary-jar-2]:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-14]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-7]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile (version managed from 1.8)
[INFO] |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile - version managed from 1.8.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.6)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |           +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.6)
[INFO] |  |  |           +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |           \- (org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.6)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - version managed from 1.0; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |        +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime - version managed from 2.5.6; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-kerberos-core:jar:1.0.0.M2:runtime
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-14]:jar:model1:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-7]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile - version managed from 1.8; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2:compile - version managed from 1.2; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-kerberos-core:jar:1.0.0.M2:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- [proprietary-jar-15]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-7]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- ([proprietary-jar-12]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- ([proprietary-jar-14]:jar:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc_license_cu:jar:9.7:test
[INFO] \- com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc4:jar:9.7fp5:test
```

Any help?

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Child not found [war project]/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar for DelegatingHandler@263476109[path=[war project]/WEB-INF/lib/divautils-1.3.jar
context=file:/C:/app/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA-2/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/C:/app/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA-2/server/default/deploy/[war project]/WEB-INF/lib/divautils-1.3.jar], available childr
en: [ZipEntryHandler@131683849[path=[war project]/WEB-INF/lib/divautils-1.3.jar/META-INF context=file:/C:/app/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA-2/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/C:/app/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.
GA-2/server/default/deploy/[war project]/WEB-INF/lib/divautils-1.3.jar/META-INF], ZipEntryHandler@1302293733[path=[war project]/WEB-INF/lib/divautils-1.3.jar/com context=file:/C:/app/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA-2/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/C:/app/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA-2/server/default/deploy/[war project]/WEB-INF/lib/divautils-1.3.jar/com]]
```

Comment: That's the error....you should look for the cause, the part of the log that tells you what caused the error.

Comment: Omoro, I added the full stack. The cause says that the spring jar was not found. But if I open the war file, it is there...
Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you build using maven, if yes, please show us the dependency details.

Comment: Hi Bennet, Yes, I used Maven. I posted the dependency tree. Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the dependency details. not tree.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
   <artifactId>geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency> try this dependency in your pom.xml and build the application and try deploying it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please forgive me. This was a totally misleading error I was getting and the problem was caused by a different application. After removing all applications from the server but the one I was testing, it started to work.

Sorry for this.